# BASH: Drop Complex Command Result into Variable

Tags: bash, shell

Here's what I've attempted:

```
$var=$(wget --spider -S "http://www.test.com/images/$image" 2>&1 | grep "HTTP/" | awk '{print $2}')
    if [ $var -eq 200 ]; then
        echo "$image|found" >> foundimages.txt
    fi
```

I need the result dropped into `var` and I need to compare it. This attempt fails to store that command result. Any ideas?

Comment: `$var=$(command)` is incorrect you want `var=$(command)`.

Comment: ...mind you, you _also_ should use `[ "$var" = 200 ]`, not `[ $var -eq 200 ]` (Quotes are mandatory for consistent behavior, and string comparison is more appropriate than numeric comparison here, since a value other than a string should return a false result, but not print an error to stderr). Several of these problems would have been caught by http://shellcheck.net/.

Answer (score 2):

for assignment `var=something` not `$var=something`:

```
var=$(wget --spider -S "http://www.test.com/images/$image" 2>&1 | grep "HTTP/" | awk '{print $2}')
```